# PyGTK and Glade 3 - How to get the output of 'print' to TextView

Tags: python, textview, pygtk, glade

I'm quite new in programming, even in speaking in English.. so I'm just trying to explain my problem here:

I'm building a GUI using Glade 3, which need show all output of 'print' in a TextView  or some Widgets else of Glade 3,

My python code is something like this:

```
#ab.py
def a():
    print 'AAAAA'

def b():
    print 'BBBBB'
```

and

```
#button_c.py
def button_c():
    if:
      print '11111'
    elif:
      print '22222'
    else:
      print '33333'

    a()
    b()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    button_c()
```

I'm trying use some code like this to show all of the output of 'print' in the object textview1 in a real time, just like the Python Interpreter did:

```
    def on_button_c_clicked(self, widget):
        button_c()
        self.builder.get_object("textview1").get_buffer().set_text(??????)
```

I've googled a lot and seeing something about sys.stdout, thread, subprocess and textbuffer, but I still can't figure it out, the only idea i have in the moment is change all 'print' parte of the code as:

```
    def a():
        # print 'AAAAA'
        output_gui = 'AAAAA'
        print output_gui
        self.builder.get_object("textview1").get_buffer().set_text(output_gui)
```

I haven't tried this yet because there must be another smarter way, no?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at Codimension (python IDE) sources. There is one of solutions. All sources written with python.

More close:

if .deb package (I have Debian linux) installed - /usr/share/codimension/ui/mainwindow.py, class CodimensionMainWindow, __ init__(), or in the same file from tarball. It uses Redirector (self-written, I think) module (very small) also - /usr/share/codimension/ui/redirector.py